# What does "X percent interest in shop" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I do not understand meaning of "in the shop" here. Can it be "50 percent from shop value?"

> Cam: Because here’s the thing about investors, Juanita—they really
> like you a whole lot better when you pay them back.
> Juanita: What
> happens if you miss a payment?
> Cam: Depends on the investor. Most were pretty reasonable. A thirty-day cure provision, meaning I had a month
> to get my act together and cough up the money. After that, it depends
> on the terms of the contract, how much I was willing to put up as
> collateral.
> Juanita: What were your terms?
> Cam: They were 50 percent
> interest **in the** shop, 50 percent of the profits and a personal
> guarantee.

K. Belle "My darling husband"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cam's last sentence describes what the [collateral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collateral_(finance)) for the loan was. That basically means what the lender would get in case Cam can't pay back the money.

Part of the collateral is "50 percent interest in the shop". This basically means that the lender would get half of the shop - not necessary literal (every second product from the shelf or something), but half of the ownership.